# Errors when filtering Firebase list using search bar

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore

I have a `ion-list` that contains data from firestore. I am trying to search data inside this list however i am unable to filter my list of items due to an undefined error: `Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined` As i am new to ionic I am not exactly sure what data i should be filtering on.

**home.html**

```
<ion-content padding>
<ion-searchbar placeholder="Filter Items" (ionInput)="filterItems($event)</ion-searchbar>
<ion-list>
<ion-item text-wrap *ngFor='let user of users'>
  <h2><strong>{{ user.name }}</strong></h2>
  <h5><strong>Phone:</strong> {{ user.phone}}</h5>
  <h5><strong>Address:</strong> {{ user.street}}, {{ user.suburb}}, {{ user.city}} {{ user.postcode}}</h5>

  <button ion-button color='secondary' (click)='updateDocument(user)'>Update this record</button>
    </ion-item>
     </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

**home.ts**

```
private _COLL   : string = "users";
private _CONTENT    : any;
public users        : any;

constructor(public navCtrl  : NavController,
           private _DB     : DatabaseProvider,
           private _ALERT  : AlertController)
{
  this._CONTENT = {
     id          : "",
     name        : "",
     phone       : "",
     street      : "",
     suburb      : "",
     city        : "",
     postcode    : ""
  };
}

ionViewDidEnter()
{
  this.retrieveCollection();
}

retrieveCollection() : void
{
  this._DB.getDocuments(this._COLL)
  .then((data) =>
  {
     this.users = data;
  })
  .catch();
}

filterItems(ev: any) {
  debugger;
  this.retrieveCollection();
  let val = ev.target.value;

  if (val && val.trim() !== '') {
    this.users.filter(function(user) {
      return user.name.toLowerCase().includes(val.toLowerCase());
    });
  }
}
```

It appears that it is the `function(user)` inside `filterItems()` that is undefined but I am not sure what I should be putting here. I would like to filter based on the users `name`

Comment: did you console log users after retrieveCollection() is called? are you sure that the data is correctly formed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether your `users` array is formed correctly.
I can see error in your html. `ion-searchbar` is not closed correctly.

```
<ion-searchbar placeholder="Filter Items" (ionInput)="filterItems($event)"> 
</ion-searchbar>
```

See my [stackblitz demo here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-7hdpnm?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)